# Restrict access to XAP file

Tags: windows-phone-7, xap

Is it possible for a user to access the XAP installation file of an app installed via the Marketplace? If yes, is it possible to restrict access to it?

I basically have some copyrighted images used in the app, and dont want the users to be able to gain access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only by hacking (ie. jailbreaking) the phone. So in short, no, users are not able to access your XAP.

On all devices in the world, you can't avoid the possibility that someone is going to crack the security measures (in this case, Microsofts). But it's very difficult on WP7, if not impossible still, as opposed to Android where it just takes a few clicks to get the content of a marketplace app, and then decompile it.

Comment: My friend wrote a blog post sometime back. http://www.martani.net/2010/12/windows-phone-7-why-you-should.html is this still valid?

Comment: No. At least it's not possible to get the XAP files that way anymore. And the ChevronWP7 tool doesn't work after the latest (NoDo) certificate update (and isn't Mango compatible). Also, a lot of decompilers can see through obfuscated code. And finally there's the thing , nobody care for your mobile phone code. People care for your data services, and embedded content such as graphics and music. All this, obfuscation have zero effect on.

Comment: His orginal link apparently still works, but none of my apps is available that way. Seems it's just for OEM apps (http://forum.mobilism.org/viewtopic.php?p=679246)

Comment: No. You can't. It only works for OEM apps. I can't download a single of my own apps (and I *do* know the APPID for them!)

Comment: Here is an example of what searching the Marketplace for nytimes shows: http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/4669/captureyuf.png the app allow you to download only the XAP of free apps (not hard to get others). And I believe if your apps are not shown, it's due to the language they are published in and not because MS protects them (there are different XML files that contains direct links to XAPs per Marketplace language) !!

Comment: And it's not the APPID that is used to construct the direct link (as the very original method), but the XML files used by Zune from the marketplace directly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now ANYONE can download your xap from the marketplace, this application for example access to free apps on the WP7 Marketplace http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/search-and-download-free-windows-phone-7-marketplace-apps-xap-files-to-pc/

For paid apps, it won't be any harder than analyzing the xml files exchanged by Zune.